# Add "+" to Cisco SPA122 (latest firmware)

Tags: ubuntu, voip, asterisk, freepbx

I use Twilio, and I'm required to use the full ISO spec "+" before all phone calls.

MY PBX is Asterisk 13.26.0, connected through private network.

I have a Cisco SPA122, with the latest firmware.  Here is my current dialplan:

`(911S0|310xxxx|<:1613>1[2-9]xx[2-9]xxxxxxS0|1[2-9]xx[2-9]xxxxxxS0|[2-9]xx[2-9]xxxxxxS0|*xx|***xxx|*xx.|[3468]11|822|0|00|4xxx|**275*x.|xxxxxxxxxxxx.)`

With this dial plan I can reach extension 8002 by calling 8002#.  However, *60 *69 do not work.

Comment: https://wiki.voip.ms/article/Dial_Plan_for_Linksys_ATAs

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue with this dialplan for USA.

It adds + after country code.

`(*xx|80xxS0|<:+>1xxxxxxxxxxS0)`

Comment: Cannot confirm the entire dial plan works, but I have a SPA122 and that is the correct way to add a number or symbol to a number. Take note if you adding more than one section: the S0 is the Interdigit Short Timer set to zero (meaning, will dial immediately once the entered digits match at least one sequence).

Comment: More infor on the Interdigit Short Timer can be found on the Cisco help site: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/voice_ip_comm/csbpipp/ip_phones/administration/guide/frame_source/500-series-7-5-7/ip_phone_admin/shared_Dial_Plan.pdf

Answer (score -2):

You should add *6[09]| to your dialplan at start.

Comment: Can you explain what this does/why it works?

Comment: That is regexp. For more info see article above. Answer is very long for SO.

Comment: Very well. Why should the OP add this particular Regex? What does it do? Good answers don't just give the answer, they teach the reader too.

Comment: Good question should show some efforts too. Anyway, you can extend if you want. If i see no attempt solve issue, i just give hint.

Comment: I added `*6[09]|` to the start of my dialplan, and I'm still not able to make outgoing calls.   The dialplan should add `+` to the start of the telephone number